# extension of a non-finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

For a finite measure on a field $\mathcal{F_0}$ there always exists its extension to $\sigma(\mathcal{F_0})$.

Can somebody give me an example of a non-finite measure on a field which cannot be extended to $\sigma(\mathcal{F_0})$.

It would be better if somebody can point in the proof (for existence of extension of finite measure), where the finite-ness property is used.

Comment: I am not sure, whether it is not possible to extend it. Rather, such an extension may not be unique.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to extend every non-finite measure. But can somebody give me an example of a measure which cannot be extended. Because for finite measures the extension is unique.


See section 1.3.2 in Robert Ash and Catherine Dade, "Probability and measure theory", second edition

Comment: why do you think it's not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every measure can be extended from a field to the generated $\sigma$-algebra. The classical proof by Caratheodory does not rely on the measure being finite, so there is no such example. As Ilya mentioned in a comment, the extension may not be unique. Here is an explicit example:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the field of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by sets of the form $(a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mu(A)=\infty$ for $A\in\mathcal{F}\backslash\{\emptyset\}$. It is easy to see that $\sigma(\mathcal{F})=P(\mathbb{Q})$, the powerset. Now let $r>0$ be a real number. Then there is a unique measure $\mu_r$ such that $\mu\big(\{q\}\big)=r$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. So for each $r>0$, $\mu_r$ is a different extension of $\mu$. So there is a continuum of possible extensions of $\mu$ to $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$. The example is based on one in *Counterexamples in Probability and Real Analysis* by Wise and Hall.

Comment: Just interested, at least a continuum of extensions, or there is a precise statement?

Comment: @Ilya Well, the argument shows that there are at least a continuum of extensions. But there are also at most a continuum many extensions, since we can identify these measures by what they do to points. So every measure corresponds to an element of $\big(\mathbb{R}_+\cup\{+\infty\}\big)^\mathbb{Q}$ and the later set has the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker correct me if I'am wrong but $\mu_r$ cannot be an extension.

Consider the sets $Q_n = (q-1/n,q]$. $Q_n \rightarrow \{q\}$, but $\mu_r(Q_n) \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @user167291 Infinite measures do not have to be continuous from above. Take sets of the form $B_n=(n,\infty)$ and Lebesgue measure. We have $B_n\downarrow \emptyset$ but $\mu(B_n)$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Since [Carathéodory's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) does not require that the spaces are sigma-finite, there is no such counterexample. (As already mentioned, in the absence of sigma-finiteness, the uniqueness disappears, not the existence.)